# Euro Character not displaying properly in HTML message Outlook 2007

Tags: html, utf-8, outlook

I am sending an e-mail message containing HTML in the body. Below is a snippet of what is giving me grief.

EDIT: Here is more of the email, with sensitive information removed

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: 
To: 
Date:
Subject:
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<strong>â‚¬3,500</strong>

</body>
</html>
```

"â‚¬" is the UTF-8 encoding of the Euro symbol. So most email clients seem to render the Euro character just fine, EXCEPT in Microsoft Outlook 2007 (maybe later versions as well), where the Euro character is displayed as this "â‚¬".

Anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: can you post sources of the email with headers? Why do you put euro sign in `<head>` tag? why don't you have a `body` tag?

Comment: @klarki, the `strong` element is not in the `head` element (still less in the `<head>` tag). It implicitly opens the `body` element.

Comment: I updated the source, when I was stripping out all the non problem code, I accidentally the body tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message's MIME headers may or may not take precedence over the HTML meta tags in different clients. You'd better make sure they both agree.

```
:
--mimeboundary
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-transfer-encoding: 8bit

<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
:
```

Comment: This might be it! I will take a peek and see if this is the problem!

Comment: If you declare `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit` you cannot expect UTF-8 to work. The most transparent fix is to use `Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable` and then obviously correspondingly encode the body part.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can try `&euro;` instead of '€'

Comment: And numerical entities where a named entity isn't available. Then the de facto character set will be entirely 7bit US-ASCII.

Comment: If this your problem entirely, please select my answer as accepted. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the HTML? Are you setting the HTMLBody property? In that case the value must be UTF-16 since all strings in IDispatch-friendly COM are 2 byte UTF-16 strings.

It would be much better to property HTML-encode the special character rather than rely on the code page conversion.